# Can GNU Screen Bindkey command be used to enter a key press?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

I would like to make a custom keybinding in GNU Screen which, when some key is pressed, like <kbd>F1</kbd>, is the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then the Screen `next` command.

I know that `bindkey` can bind keys to Screen commands, but could it also be used to trigger some other command line input, such as the mere pressing of the "enter" key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `stuff` screen command. From the man pages of `screen`:

> ```
>    stuff [string]
>
>    Stuff  the string string in the input buffer of the current window.  This is
>    like the "paste" command but with much less overhead.  Without  a  paramter,
>    screen  will  prompt  for a string to stuff.  You cannot paste large buffers
>    with the "stuff" command. It is most  useful  for  key  bindings.  See  also
>    "bindkey".
> ```

Also in the man pages you can see the following examples:

> ```
>            bindkey -k k1 select 1
>    Make the "F1" key switch to window one.
>
>            bindkey -t foo stuff barfoo
>    Make  "foo"  an  abbreviation  of the word "barfoo". Timeout is disabled so that
>    users can type slowly.
> ```

So for instance, you can add the following line to your `$HOME/.inputrc` file to bind <kbd>F1</kbd> writing `\n` to the input buffer (the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
bindkey -k k1 stuff "\n"
```